# How to call a Matlab user-created function in a .m file from Mathematica?

Tags: matlab, matlink

I have a file called gensys.m where it's defined a function `gensys`, which I would like to call in the mathematica environment and work with it.

I've tried to download MatLink, but it doesn't seem to work... It seems to need MatLab which I don't have...

Assuming I had Matlab, is the best way to work with the function `gensys`, through MatLink?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Best way would be indeed to use MatLink. Of course MatLab is mandatory. Most MatLab code can also be executed with the free [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) interpreter. Unfortunately, MatLink cannot be used with Octave; the developers refrained from doing so for [licence reasons](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/147140). If the code is not too long and does not involve exotic libraries, the simplest way would be to translate it by hand.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the comment ;)